# When I am building meta-toolchain-qt5 using yocto I encountered following error

Tags: linux

```
ERROR: qtbase-5.9.2+gitAUTOINC+ec16ba393b-r0
do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: The file /usr/lib/pkgconfig/wayland-egl.pc is installed by both mesa and imx-gpu-viv, aborting ERROR:
qtbase-5.9.2+gitAUTOINC+ec16ba393b-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot:
Function failed: extend_recipe_sysroot ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
/home/sandeep/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.2+gitAUTOINC+ec16ba393b-r0/temp/log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.2803 ERROR: Task
(/home/sandeep/fsl-community-bsp/sources/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bb:do_prepare_recipe_sysroot)
failed with exit code '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

mesa and imx-gpu-viv both recipe files are trying to insta the same file      `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/wayland-egl.pc`  that is cause the error. Remove the file manually and compile it again .